# Modify a directory without changing the timestamp

Tags: shell

Is there a way to copy file A into directory B without changing B's timestamps? If yes, then what is it?

edit:

The larger goal: I'm digging through some code I wrote more than a year ago. I found that there were somethings I did which will always be confusing to my future self. I want to add a README file there explaining the gotcha. But I want to preserve the last time I worked in that directory.

Finally:

Thanks for both the answers. I ended up doing "touch -r B/newestoldfile B" which was good enough for my purpose. Even though like someone pointed out, that isn't the exact answer to my question in all circumstances. I voted up both the answer but had to pick on as accepted. I chose the one that briefly mentioned the -r option :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's your larger goal?

Comment: No, but you might be able to set its modification time back to what it was afterwards (think [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) command, or [`utime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html) function call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the timestamp from the directory before copying with `stat -c %Y` and then use the `touch` command to modify the timestamp after.

If you simply want to copy the timestamp from directory A to B :

```
touch -r A B
```

Comment: That will use A's time which isn't necessarily the old time of B. This doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: Thanks, I added comments to my question.

Comment: Given the edit to the question, it would probably be good to remove the strikethrough. Sorry for the back and forth.

Comment: I meant keep the text that was striken through, but make it clear again. It contained the answer that was used.

Answer (score 3):

Capture the old mtime of the B directory. Then move the file, then rewrite the mtime of the B directory with old mtime that  you have stored, using the `touch` command.

```
old_mtime=$(stat -c%Y B)
mv A B
touch -d"$(date --date="@$old_time")" B
```

We use `@$old_time` to create the date representing by `$old_time` seconds since epoch, which is what `stat` gives us.

Comment: Thanks, I added comments to my question.

Comment: You might want to use LC_ALL=C before calling date. Like `touch -d"$(LC_ALL=C date --date="@$old_time")" B` in case touch doesn't recognize the date output in your locale.

Answer (score 1):

When you code, you should use a Source Control System like [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). It allows you to create a repository of the files of your project, edit the files, register the versions with comments on what you changed, eventually merge the edited files into the project, host it in the cloud by using a distributed system.

Others already replied correctly referring to the method you mentioned, but i wanted to give you a better suggestion using another solution that you'd better use also in the future.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I do use subversion and bazaar. This was meant to be quick and dirty hack. And besides I still rely on file timestamps even when I'm using version control, sometimes.